# How can i parse some java script part from a web page as text to a text file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The web page is:

[Google Tennis Results](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=australian%20open%20atp)

What i'm trying to get as text is the tennis results in the top of the page.
Tried using webBrowser now but not getting it at all.
Not sure if it's also java script in the page or not but i can't parse it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            test1();
        }



        private void test1()
        {
            this.webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new MyScript();
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        public class MyScript
        {
            public void CallServerSideCode()
            {
                var doc = ((Form1)Application.OpenForms[0]).webBrowser1.Document;
                var renderedHtml = doc.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].OuterHtml;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=australian%20open%20atp");
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript: window.external.CallServerSideCode();");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use a feed like RSS, Atom Feed, or any API from the website instead of reading web page. Web Page would be dynamic and would change the content.

Comment: I didn't find how to use rss atom or api. I tried to use the google search api but it didn't give me the results part.

Comment: I also tried using webBrowser to navigate to the page and then somehow to parse/extract the text from the page but still can't get the results part as text.